# How to make this layout in CSS?

Tags: css, layout, html

[This layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtVj8.png)

I don't even know how to name it. "Fluid" or "liquid" columns seems to refer to simple dynamic heights. I made this one with and got two questions: is it possible to do it with raw HTML5/CSS3? Is it possible to make it work for 3, 4, ..., n columns?!

Comment: Yes. It is possible to do it with raw HTML5/CSS3.

Comment: You might find something like this helpful - http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtVj8.png)
You can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) -  which is pure JavaScript & also supports jQuery  
 or
[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which is a jQuery Plugin. 
Author of these plugins suggests to use [Isotope](https://github.com/desandro/isotope).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I need. Just by curiosity, is it possible to get the same effect (without the animation, of course) with bare CSS?

Comment: No, just with CSS it's not possible, if you see the [Layout modes:](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html) it's explained there. Try a [demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), resizing your browser with options - `showall, original, mansory` you will find gaps, that are actually removed by Layout Modes which uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you will set the heights of each read box. If it is content dependent, then it's just a 2 column layout with fluid widths. If you are maintaining a height to width ratio, then you will need to use js to do the math and maintain the height or use an img for the background `width:100%; height:auto; display:block` and position the content `position:absolute:` on top of it.