# Fill available space with or without flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Inside my `<main>` element I have divs, each with the class `.dataCard`. Each `.dataCard` has the same minimum dimensions, but as soon as I started adding content to the `.dataCard`s I noticed the layout behaving weirdly.

The `<main>` element is separated into two columns each containing a `.dataCard`. I did this because I need the order of the `.dataCard` to go left-column, then one in right-column, one in left-column, and so on.

But when I fill the `.dataCard`s with content they push all the other cards down underneath them.

How can I fill the available space with the `.dataCard`s so that the `<main>` element that contains them is as small in height as possible.

Right now, in the link below, there is the second card in the right column, but then a bunch of whitespace and at the end of the second-card the 3rd card in the left column starts.

How can I move the left column up, or in other words, make the cards fit the available space with or without flexbox?

I would greatly appreciate any and all help!

[Here is the link: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcVDBweWk2UXlfTVE/KE.html](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcVDBweWk2UXlfTVE/KE.html)

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand that you want to fill the entire page with boxes without any space.

[This is what, exactly you wanted.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17224137/1008278)

Comment: I tried masonary. It doesn't work. It puts all the cards in one column.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to use isotope? I don't see any getting started guides. And the index.html that I got from github is written in some compressed HTML.

Comment: http://digitalunion.osu.edu/2013/03/15/jquery-isotope-a-brief-introduction-and-tutorial/    http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried isotope, but it is not resulting in what I am trying to do. I tried fitRows, fitColumns, and masonary layouts, but they all put the items into one column all at the top. Can you update your answer with what I need to do to achieve this layout?

Comment: Yes, here is what I get when I try using Masonry. https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcVDBweWk2UXlfTVE/KE%20copy.html

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me get this layout with Masonry or IsoTope.

Comment: Yes, I understand. but I can't, I have my own work. very sorry :(